# Jersey 2 inject dependencies into unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a controller like this

```
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AccountController implements CRUDController<Long, Account> {

    private AccountDao accountDao;
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Inject
    public AccountController(AccountDao accountDao, AccountService accountService) {
        this.accountDao = accountDao;
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }
...
```

I'm injecting AccountDao and AccountService using

```
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig()
               .packages("controller", "exception")
               .register(new MyDIBinder());
```

Where MyDIBinder is contains all the bindings (e.g

```
AccountDaoImpl accountDaoImpl = new AccountDaoImpl();
bind(accountDaoImpl).to(AccountDao.class);
```

)

Now I want to write a unit test for this controller, is it possible to inject the whole AccountController instance with all of it's transitive dependencies into the test?

Something like

```
    @Inject
    AccountController accountController;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the main IoC container, and just explicitly inject the test class. Jersey uses HK2 as its DI framework, and its IoC container is the `ServiceLocator`, which has a method `inject(anyObject)` that can inject any objects with dependencies that are in its registry.

For example you could do something like

```
public class InjectionTest {

    @Inject
    private TestController controller;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        final Binder b = new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bindAsContract(TestController.class);
            }
        };
        final ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(new TestBinder(), b);
        locator.inject(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void doTest() {
        assertNotNull(controller);
        String response = controller.get();
        assertEquals("Hello Tests", response);
    }
}
```

The `ServiceLocatorUtilities` class is a helper class that allows us to easily create the `ServiceLocator`, and then we just call `inject(this)` to inject the `InjectionTest`.

If it seems repetitive to do this for all your controller tests, you may want to create an abstract base test class. Maybe something like

```
public abstract class AbstractControllerTest {

    protected ServiceLocator locator;
    private final Class<?> controllerClass;

    protected AbstractControllerTest(Class<?> controllerClass) {
        this.controllerClass = controllerClass;
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        final AbstractBinder binder = new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bindAsContract(controllerClass);
            }
        };
        locator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(new TestBinder(), binder);
        locator.inject(this);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        if (locator != null) {
            locator.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your concrete class

```
public class TestControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTest {

    public TestControllerTest() {
        super(TestController.class);
    }

    @Inject
    private TestController controller;

    @Test
    public void doTest() {
        assertNotNull(controller);
        assertEquals("Hello Tests", controller.get());
    }
}
```

If you spent some more time, I'm sure you could come up with a better abstract test class design. It was the first thing that came to mind for me.

Note: For anything request scoped, you mayb need to just mock it. When running the *unit* tests, there is no request context, so the test will fail.

**See Also:**

- [Using Jersey's Dependency Injection in a Standalone application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30789297/2587435)
- [HK2 documentation](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b07/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What is a TestBinder?

Comment: It is a binder I used to test my example. It just contained a simple service binding. For you, it would be MyDIBinding

Comment: @peeskillet please complete this response with an TestBinder example.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;

@BeforeClass
    public static void doTest() {
        ServiceLocator serviceLocator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindAsContract(YourClass1.class);
                bindAsContract(YourClass2.class);
                bindAsContract(YourClass3.class);
            }
        });

        YourClass1 yourClass1 = serviceLocator.getService(YourClass1.class);
        ...
```