# jersey - test rest endpoint service with ejb injection

Tags: jersey, grizzly

I got a jax-rs resource

```
@Path("rest/v1/serviceemail")
public class PreviewResource implements Preview
{  
  @EJB
  private Mapper mapper;
```

I'm creating an IT test with jersey-test-framework-core and jersey-test-framework-grizzly2.

When I launch the test the ejb is not injected in the service and so I receive a NPE.

Comment: Mock the `Mapper`. Unless you need a full integration test, then you need something that can load a full EE environment. Maybe like arquillian.

Comment: You can see one way [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27447345/2587435) of mocking the `Mapper` using Mockito

Comment: I was thinking about an Integration Test because the unit test is already done; so I would like to use a light EE embedded container.

Comment: I would check out arquillian. That is actually the only one I know, so I  can't really suggest any others.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by implementing a custom *InjectableProvider*. The following code is taken from an [Oracle article](https://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/ejb_injection):

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentContext;
import com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentScope;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.InjectableProvider;

@Provider
public class EJBProvider implements InjectableProvider<EJB, Type> {

    public Scope getScope() {
        return Scope.Singleton;
    }

    public Injectable getInjectable(ComponentContext cc, EJB ejb, Type t) {
        if (!(t instanceof Class)) return null;

        try {
            Class c = (Class)t;        
            Context ic = new InitialContext();

            final Object o = ic.lookup(c.getName());

            return new Injectable<Object>() {
                public Object getValue(HttpContext c) {
                    return o;
                }                    
            };            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I had to slightly adapt it to fit my environment. Also note that the provider has to be in the same package as your service class, otherwise it won't be picked up (it does not say that in the article).

Comment: Can you provide more details or maybe add an integration test as an example?