# What is advantage of using Jersey instead of Spring MVC in spring boot for REST API?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

We need to develop the web application based on micro service arch but I am bit confused what is benefit of using jersey in a spring-boot application. As spring-boot in build features also gives power to expose web services, so what jersey will do when used with spring-boot.

Is jersey more secure and robust as compared to spring mvc. Please suggest which is best way to expose rest api in a spring-boot app, TIA.

Comment: You can read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824423/what-is-the-difference-among-spring-rest-service-and-jersey-rest-service-and-spr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Spring REST plays better with other Spring API’s (use api 2.0.6), but that is only valuable if you are a full-fledged Spring shop.
2. I’ve played with early versions of Spring so haven’t had a chance to compare Spring 4’s support for REST vs Jersey in detail. My high-level comparisons did not indicate anything radical in Spring REST that enticed me to move completely away from Jersey.
3. I can use Jersey in Spring-based applications just as other applications. It’s easy to use and I haven’t noticed any major performance issues during run-time. It’s also older and most bugs have been sorted out over the years. Just one less thing to worry about.
   =======================------------------========================

Comment: is there any winning point where I can drop spring mvx just because of jersey?

Comment: what about versioning of APIs?

Comment: I have updated the answer. for more details plz visit this link:https://jersey.github.io/